# Экспорт отчета на русском языке в PDF (jasperreports)

Tags: jasperreports, java

Гугл выдаёт много, но по старым версиям, по которым уже концов не найдёшь.
Отчет берет данные из БД. Данные на русском языке. В отчете есть pieChart и несколько textField. После экспорта в PDF (через Java) текст на круговой диаграмме отображается отлично, а вот в textField вообще не отображается, как будто его там нет. Когда данные на английском - везде отображается хорошо. Помогите плиз. Использую iReport 4, библиотека той же версии.
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Проблему смог решить, конкретно указав шрифт внутри textField.

```
        <textField>
                <reportElement key="textField" x="47" y="6" width="173"height="20"/><textElement>
    <font
      fontName="Liberation Sans"
      pdfFontName="/home/{username}/expFonts/LiberationSans-Regular.ttf"
      size="14"
      isBold="false"
      isItalic="false"
      isUnderline="false"
      isPdfEmbedded ="true"
      pdfEncoding ="Cp1251"
      isStrikeThrough="false"
     />
</textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
```

Comment: именно так

Answer (score 1):

С некоторыми шрифтами экспорт в PDF на русском языке проходит без проблем.

Например DejaVu:

```
fontName="DejaVu Serif"
```

:

```
<style name="DetailFieldsStyle" 
  fill="Solid" 
  hAlign="Center" 
  vAlign="Middle" 
  isBlankWhenNull="true" 
  fontName="DejaVu Serif" 
  fontSize="10" 
  isBold="false" 
  isItalic="false" 
  isUnderline="false" 
  isStrikeThrough="false"
>
....
<textField>
    <reportElement style="DetailFirstFieldStyle" x="315" y="0" width="105" height="27"/>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{STATUS}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Answer (score 1):

Тоже помучался, пока не нашел. По умолчанию, для русского языка, в JasperStudio выставляется шрифт Sans-Sherif, который отображает только английский язык. Поменял на Arial, русский отобразился